# checking server updates using services after user login

Tags: android

hi all i need to start a service  when user clicks login button , this service have to check the server updates for each five minutes,and when the user log off this service have to stop. can any body tell me how could i achieve this.if possible help me with sample codings.thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

There are tons of examples available for service, the official android site has it too http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html

My suggestion is that you use a alarm service to invoke your service in the specified interval. You can terminate it when you too as well. [Alarm Manager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html) details are here. But note that The Alarm Manager is intended for cases where you want to have your application code run at a specific time, even if your application is not currently running. For normal timing operations (ticks, timeouts, etc) it is easier and much more efficient to use Handler.